# Show content according to dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of object say `[{country:"US",name:"ABC"},{country:"China",name:"PQR"},{country:"AUS",name:"XYZ"}]`

I want on dropdown selection the Content of list should show. Like if I select a country "US" Only "ABC" should come.

I made the Dropdown and in state i am saving the selected country it as `selectedCountry`

How to show name based on the `selectedCountry`.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Test() {
    let data = [
                 { country: "US", name: "ABC" },
                 { country: "China", name: "PQR" },
                 { country: "AUS", name: "XYZ" },
 ];
     const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState("")
 return (
  <>
    <div>
      <select value={selectedCountry} onChange={(e)=>setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}>
             {data.map((item)=>{
      return <option value={item.name}>{item.country}</option>  
      })}
    </select>
    <p>{selectedCountry}</p>
  </div>
</>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const filteredArray= countryArray.filter(country=> country ===selectedCountry);
country = filteredArray0;